# Decompress file from assets folder and use it from phonepag application and protect it

Tags: java, android, html, cordova

My idea is to have a file with password and decompress to a folder where i can use them in a phonegap application . 
Use html files in a new location.
 I think that is my way to protect phonegap application from decompile.

any idea how to do that ?
thanks

Comment: You can do it any way you want.

Comment: i need to know to do that from java , i need an idea, i am a newbie

Comment: Your idea to put such a file in the assets folder is ok.